# How to deploy on forge when using queue

Tags: deployment, laravel-5, queue, webhooks, forge

I have a project on forge with one queue worker (with database driver).
Currently I need manually restart queue worker after each deploy:
[image]

My deployment script:

```
cd /home/forge/default
git pull origin master
git log -1
composer install --no-interaction --no-dev --prefer-dist
php artisan migrate --force
```

How extend my script for automatic restart queue worker?

I tried `php artisan queue:restart`. But this command just truncate all items in queue. And uptime of worker didn't reset.

Perhaps I can use `failed-table`, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using Laravel forge, I'm assuming you are also using supervisor. You can restart supervisor in your deployment script which will restart all queue workers.

```
sudo supervisorctl restart all
```

If you don't want to restart all workers, supervisortctl restart has options too.

```
restart <name>      Restart a process
restart <gname>:*   Restart all processes in a group
restart <name> <name>   Restart multiple processes or groups
restart all     Restart all processes
```

Answer (score 1):

Running `php artisan queue:restart` would also restart supervisor and you won't need to do `sudo supervisorctl` as a forge user.